# Invalid Parse.com request

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have been using parse for a while now and I am quite confused by the issue I am having.

Here is one function that I call first:

```
 $scope.followUser = function(usernameToFollow)
  {
    console.log('ready to follow user:   ' + usernameToFollow);

    var user = Parse.User.current();

    if (user)
    {
        var FollowUser = Parse.Object.extend('User');
        var query = new Parse.Query(FollowUser);
        query.equalTo('username', usernameToFollow);
        query.find({
            success: function(results)
            {
                var relationToUserPosts = user.relation('followUser');

                $scope.userToAdd = results[0];//This is the user I want to add relational data to

                relationToUserPosts.add(results[0]);

                user.save();

            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                alert('Error: ' + error.code + '' + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Need to login a user');
        // show the signup or login page
    }


};
```

Next after I call that function I call this function:

```
$scope.addToFollowers = function()
{
    var currUser = Parse.User.current();
    console.log($scope.userToAdd);
    var followerUser = $scope.userToAdd.relation('followers');

    followerUser.add(currUser);


    $scope.userToAdd.save();

};
```

I know for sure the $scope.userToAdd is the user I want, I know the relation I pull from the object is valid its when I try to save this object with $scope.userToAdd.save() is when I get the bad request, with no further information as to why its a bad request. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
The first method call has no errors and no bad requests.
Error message:
[image: Error message expanded]

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Only that it is a bad parse request I have now attached the error message

Comment: You could see the response via chrome's developer tools -> network -> the request -> response.

Comment: That helped but how do I fix it?

Comment: That helped but how do I fix it? The error code is 206 which is usercannotbealteredwithoutsessionerror I checked parse but they didn't have a solution.

Comment: Well turns out you cannot save a user object unless your are logged in as that user time to find another solution thank you for the help eth3lbert.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out you cannot save a user object unless your are logged in as that user time to find another solution thank you for the help eth3lbert.

Comment: Yes, only owner(user) has permission to update the user object or update with masterKey which would ignore the permission setting.

Comment: Can I get a master key and edit the user without logging them in?

Comment: If so, you should do it via could function.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in angular client side?

Comment: No, you should not expose masterKey to client.

Comment: I know I shouldn't but this is a school project that has become a mess that just needs to work now.

Comment: Actually, its really easy to change your code into cloud function.

Comment: I'd rather just deal with getting the master key right now and not deal with parse back end. Do you know how to get it client side? I would really appreciate this quick fix.I know its never good to give master key client side but this is school project group code that I just need to get working.

Comment: Sorry, you even not allow to initialize Parse with masterKey.

Comment: Yulp your right tried changing it myself and got big alert saying unauthorized. I am glad they don't allow it easily but that just makes my project that much more complex with all group members.  Thanks for the help.